# Find out which row has fired a trigger on a table (SQL 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, backup, row

I would like to know which row has fired a trigger on a table.
The reason therefore is that I would like to backup only the changed row to a backup table.
For example I have a table with the fields `ID`, `NAME`, `ADDRESS`, `CITY` and when one of those fields has updated, deleted or inserted I would make a copy of that row to the backup table, but only that changed row, not the whole table.

Creating a trigger that makes a backup of the complete table is easy but I can't find a solution to backup only the changed row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the same solution, hereby the code I used to accomplish the task:

```
USE [MyTable]
GO

/**** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trg_MappingHistory]    Script Date: 03/20/2012 09:08:34 ****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_MappingHistory] ON [dbo].[Mappings]
    AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON ;

        DECLARE @HistoriekNrNew INT ;

        SELECT  @HistoriekNrNew = MAX([dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[HistoriekNr]) + 1
        FROM    [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek]

        IF @HistoriekNrNew IS NULL 
            BEGIN
                SET @HistoriekNrNew = 1
            END

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
        INSERT  INTO MappingsHistoriek
                ( [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[EntiteitNaam] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[AppID] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[LijstID] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Versie] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[LijstNaam] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Waarde] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Type] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Datum] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Gebruiker] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[HistoriekNr],
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Actie]
                )
                SELECT  [dbo].[Entiteit].[Naam] ,
                        deleted.[AppID] ,
                        deleted.[LijstID] ,
                        deleted.[LijstNaam] ,
                        deleted.[Versie] ,
                        deleted.[Waarde] ,
                        deleted.[Type] ,
                        GETDATE() ,
                        SYSTEM_USER ,
                        @HistoriekNrNew ,
                        'DELETED'
                FROM    deleted
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Entiteit] ON Entiteit.ID = deleted.AppID

        INSERT  INTO MappingsHistoriek
                ( [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[EntiteitNaam] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[AppID] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[LijstID] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Versie] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[LijstNaam] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Waarde] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Type] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Datum] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Gebruiker] ,
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[HistoriekNr],
                  [dbo].[MappingsHistoriek].[Actie]
                )
                SELECT  [dbo].[Entiteit].[Naam] ,
                        inserted.[AppID] ,
                        inserted.[LijstID] ,
                        inserted.[LijstNaam] ,
                        inserted.[Versie] ,
                        inserted.[Waarde] ,
                        inserted.[Type] ,
                        GETDATE() ,
                        SYSTEM_USER ,
                        @HistoriekNrNew ,
                        'INSERTED'
                FROM    inserted
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Entiteit] ON Entiteit.ID = inserted.AppID


    END

GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the inserted table within the trigger - it shows inserts and updates - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx for an example

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`CREATE TRIGGER` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx):

> DML triggers use the `deleted` and `inserted` logical (conceptual)
>   tables. They are structurally similar to the table on which the
>   trigger is defined, that is, the table on which the user action is
>   tried. The deleted and inserted tables hold the old values or new
>   values of the rows that may be changed by the user action.

Comment: Thanks, came to the same solution. Hereby the code I used to solve the problem:

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server exposes within a trigger the changes made to a table through two "virtual" tables named `deleted` and `inserted`. In case of an insert operation `inserted` contains the newly inserted data and deleted is empty, in case of a delete operation `inserted` is empty and the `deleted` table contains the deleted rows. In case of an update operation the `inserted` table contains the changed rows after the update and `deleted` the rows before the update.

Both tables are structurally identical to the base table. You can use the function `update()`
in case of an update event, to check if some specific column was updated.